# Include NA as a possible subsetting factor with ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I want to be able to run tests on my data by all possible combinations of categorical variables, including the possibility of subsetting by just one and not the others. As an example, take the following data:

```
dbh <- runif(100,5,40)
err <- runif(100,0,4)
height <- dbh^.8 + err
elevation <- factor(rep(c("L","M","H"),100)[1:100], levels=c("L","M","H",NA))
aspect <- factor(rep(c("E","W"),50), levels=c("E","W",NA))
dat <- data.frame(dbh, height, aspect, elevation)
```

To get the mean dbh for all combinations of aspect and elevation I tried

```
library(plyr)
result <- ddply( dat, c("elevation","aspect"), summarise, mean(dbh))
```

However, this only takes the mean of the following subsets:

```
  elevation aspect      ..1
1         L      E 26.07509
2         L      W 23.78510
3         M      E 26.72313
4         M      W 20.88566
5         H      E 19.63125
6         H      W 18.60170
```

And I would like it to take the mean of the following:

```
factors <- data.frame(elevation = rep(c("H","M","L",NA),3),
   aspect = c(rep("E",4),rep("W",4), rep(NA,4)))

   elevation aspect
1       H     E
2       M     E
3       L     E
4    <NA>     E
5       H     W
6       M     W
7       L     W
8    <NA>     W
9       H  <NA>
10      M  <NA>
11      L  <NA>
12   <NA>  <NA>
```

Can ddply be coerced to return this result?

Comment: Your use of `NA` is what's confusing people, I think, since you seem to be using it to represent _subgroup totals_ rather than missing values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since those are overlapping categories, I don't think you can use any single split-apply-combine strategy to get that result. So just get the results separately and `rbind` them (or rather `rbind.fill` them, to compensate for different columns):

```
rbind.fill(ddply( dat, c("elevation","aspect"), summarise, mean(dbh)),
           ddply( dat, "elevation", summarise, mean(dbh)),
           ddply( dat, "aspect", summarise, mean(dbh)),
           data.frame('..1' = mean(dat$dbh)))
```

Comment: you should probably ask that as a separate question (or edit OP) - I can't think of a way off the top of my head, but somebody else might (and they are probably not very likely to see your comments here); also please take @joran's comment into account - your question phrasing is very confusing